# The best way to open two files

Tags: python, file, text, sl4a

I need to open a file, read a line, hash it, and then save to a different file. Should I open both text files at the beginning of my script, or should I open each every time I save/read? I'm new to all this and I'm using python for android for sl4a. This is my code so far:

```
import android
import hashlib
import time
name = 0
droid = android.Android()
name = raw_input("Enter a password to hash: ")
hash_object = hashlib.md5 (name)
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
time.sleep(2)
print name

f = open('name.txt', 'w',) 
f.write(hash_object.hexdigest())
f.close()
```

Comment: Only looks like you're opening one file here?

Comment: Don't open/close every time. From my experience, it is slower. Someone else can run a benchmark, or you could. Just open them both at the beginning and close them both when you're done using them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes should open both at the beginning and iterate through closing when you are done.

so instead of reading input from the user you want to read if from a file, say something like this:

```
import android
import hashlib
import time
name = 0
droid = android.Android()
 
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_out:
for line in f_in.readlines():
    hash_object = hashlib.md5 (line)
    f_out.write(hash_object.hexdigest())
```

Comment: this should probably use the `with` idiom like the answer below

Comment: @Connor Why should one do this?

Comment: using with is the preferred way per https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using with is also much shorter than writing equivalent try-finally blocks:

Answer (score 20):

If you want to read from the file `name.txt` and write to another:

```
with open('name.txt', 'r') as f, open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:
    line = f.next()  # get first line
    hash_object = hashlib.md5 (line)
    f1.write(hash_object.hexdigest()) # write to second file
```

Comment: Is there any version issue related issue of this code? This code working fine in Python2.7 but raising a syntax error when executing in Python2.6.

Comment: [Padraic Cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) I tried to open two files in 'r' mode, but I could not get the first file content, could you explain to me why, please ? Any proposition or solution is welcomed.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer. ***Always***  open using `with`

Comment: Why should one use this approach instead of another?